# Ember data what is the right way to shard data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use ember-data and I have a data model which looks like this:

I have multiple books and each books have got pages.
Usually a user will only read a few books and there could be a lot of books. Getting all pages for a book is actually super soft on the backend.

So here's what I want to do:
/books displays all the books titles, summary... (not loading their pages).
/books/{id}/pages returns the highest pages (but loads the entire book).
/books/{id}/pages/{id} returns a page and some info (no load necessary or load the entire book if it doesn't exist already).

So I wrote these routes:

```
App.PagesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var books = this.modelFor("books");
    // Find all the rules for this book
    return this.store.find('rules', {"books": books.id});
  }
});

App.PagesGetRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var books = this.modelFor("books");
    this.store.find('rules', {"books": books.id});
    return this.store.find('rules', params.rules_id);
  }
});
```

This works pretty well. As long as a user stays in one book. When the user decides to change book. The data for the other book has not been loaded so it's empty.

I really can't do a getAll('rules') because this query will just be way too big.
I am not sure ember-data is actually supposed to be able to handle these kind of stuff. If that's not the case I will unfortunately have to drop it which is a shame because I was hoping to save time with this.

EDIT here are my routes as it might actually be an error there:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  // Add your routes here
  this.resource('news', function() {
    this.route('get', { "path": "/:news_id"});
  });

  this.resource('books', function() {
    this.resource('books', {"path": ":books_id"}, function() {
      this.resource('pages', function() {
        this.route('get', { "path": ":pages_id"});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzk655gk/6/

Comment: Which route is failing when changing books? `App.PagesGetRoute`?

Comment: They don't fail it's just if you change book the data is not here. So nothing is displayed.

Comment: But is that only in the `App.PagesGetRoute`?

Comment: Are you getting the parent book when you switch books. If pages belong to a book and if youre using `this.modelFor('books')` it sounds like you need to get the parent book model before you can get the pages for that book.

Comment: Hmm that might be it. I've just added my routes if it helps.
Does that mean I should find('books') at the begining of the route or should this be done somewhere else?

Comment: Why do you have 2 `books` resources. They might be conflicting. Shouldn't the sub `books` be just `book`

Comment: yup as @tikotzky said you have a route for books that is /books but then you redeclare it as /books/id.

Comment: Because I systematically make my models/routes... uncountable. If you don't agree with this imagine these are `news` instead of `books`. 
Though should I make the resource `books` (index) and then make a route inside it for show? 
How do I get my pages to have URIs like `/books/{book_id}/pages/{page_id}` ?

Comment: `this.resource('books', {"path": "/books"}, function() {
    this.resource('book', {"path": "/:book_id"}, function() {
      this.resource('pages', {"path": "/pages"}, function() {
        this.route('get', { "path": "/:page_id"});`  -- I left in the parent route paths just to be explicit

Comment: If all you are using the parent route is for the url, you should be able to do something like this in the subroute `this.resource('books', {"path": "/books/:books_id"}.....`

Comment: Hmm but what if I am not dealing with `book(s)` but `rice`,`news` or `advice`?
This actually doesn't solve my problem. I am going to try to reproduce it in a js fiddle. So describing the problem will be easier

Comment: yeah a fiddle would be great :)

Comment: I added a fiddle and I can't manage to reproduce there. This is a different version of ember in js fiddle. So I am wondering if it might be a bug. I'll try to upgrade on my side and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to more recent versions. This stopped happening:

```
-    "ember": "1.6.1",
+    "ember": "1.8.1",
     "handlebars": "1.3.0",
-    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.8"
+    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12"
```